# How to zip two strings?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two lists:

```
country_name = ['South Africa', 'India', 'United States']
country_code = ['ZA', 'IN', 'US']
```

I want to group the country name and its corresponding code together and then perform a sort operation to do some processing

When I tried to zip these 2 lists, I am getting the 1st character from both the lists as the output.

I also tried doing this:

```
for i in xrange(0,len(country_code):
     zipped = zip(country_name[i][:],country_code[i][:])
     ccode.append(zipped)
```

to zip the entire string, but it didn't work. Also I am not sure that after zipping the 2 list, I will be able to sort the resulting list or not.

Comment: Uh, why not just `zip(country_name, country_code)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

answer is in your question - use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> country_name = ['South Africa', 'India', 'United States']
>>> country_code = ['ZA', 'IN', 'US']
>>> zip(country_name, country_code)
[('South Africa', 'ZA'), ('India', 'IN'), ('United States', 'US')]
```

If you have lists with different lengths, you could use [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest):

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> country_name = ['South Africa', 'India', 'United States', 'Netherlands']
>>> country_code = ['ZA', 'IN', 'US']
>>> list(izip_longest(country_name, country_code))
[('South Africa', 'ZA'), ('India', 'IN'), ('United States', 'US'), ('Netherlands', None)]
```

Answer (score 7):

You are using `zip()` wrong; use it with the two lists:

```
zipped = zip(country_name, country_code)
```

You are applying it to each country name and country code *individually*:

```
>>> zip('South Africa', 'ZA')
[('S', 'Z'), ('o', 'A')]
```

`zip()` combines the two input *sequences* by pairing off each element; in strings, the individual characters are the elements of the sequence. Because there are only two characters in the country codes, you end up with lists of two elements, each a tuple of paired characters.

Once you combined both lists into a new one, you can most certainly sort that list, either on the first or second element:

```
>>> zip(country_name, country_code)
[('South Africa', 'ZA'), ('India', 'IN'), ('United States', 'US')]
>>> sorted(zip(country_name, country_code))
[('India', 'IN'), ('South Africa', 'ZA'), ('United States', 'US')]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(zip(country_name, country_code), key=itemgetter(1))
[('India', 'IN'), ('United States', 'US'), ('South Africa', 'ZA')]
```